# Formal word for "gotten made"

Tags: single-word-requests, formality

Is there a formal term for "*gotten made*" or "*gotten synthesized*"?

To be more clear lets assume that I have a design for a special chair; I ask the carpenter to fix it for me because I don't have the tools. It won't be appropriate to say that the carpenter made/fabricated/manufactured the chair. I want to emphasize my importance in this process.

**Edit:** I need a term that can be used in passive voice. Something like:

> This chair was *gotten-made* from xyz carpentry services

Any suggestions?

Comment: You question is quite confusing, first you want a term which refer to the 'act of making', now you appear to be looking for an adjective that defines the abilities of craftsmen!!!

Comment: Better? I'll clarify the situation. I am not "looking for an adjective that defines the abilities of craftsmen". I am looking for a word that would suggest that I instructed the carpenter to make me something and the ability is all mine. (I am sounding very selfish but What I have to say that the basic design is mine, the implementation of which was outsourced to some agency)

Comment: See the edit in the question: I dont care what agency made it. I want to emphasize that I told them to make it.

Comment: You mean that the external agent just has to 'execute' you instructions?

Comment: yes.. but I dont want to emphasize on their act but rather on mine for having instructed them.

Comment: To order: 
To give an order or orders; request that something be done or supplied.

Comment: You mean a way to say that you ***had*** something made to order?  I wouldn’t call that a gotten-made thing.  That sounds weird.  Also, what do you mean by all this formality bit?

Comment: I wanted to say that I had had something made for me. Now how to say that in passive voice.

Comment: The obvious word is just plain old **made**.  This is being over thought.

Answer (score 3):

**Commissioned**

a) An instruction, command, or role given to a person or group

b) An order for something, especially a work of art, to be produced specially:

*"Mozart at last received a commission to write an opera"*

c) A work produced in response to a commission

Source: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/commission

Answer (score 2):

In the vein of @AlanSutherland's "*commissioned*", consider

> ***custom ordered*** (by *you*)
>
> ***made to order*** (by *ABC Carpentry*)
>
> For adjectives, ***custom tailored*** or simply ***tailored*** (in the US), or ***bespoke*** (in the UK, or pretentiously in the US)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind drawing attention to yourself (as seems to be the case here), you could say

I **had** the chair made / constructed / crafted from ... (recycled plastic or whatever)

Comment: How to say this in passive voice? I have to write it in a report and everywhere else passive voice is used.

Comment: Oh yes sorry, you did mention that.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe *engaged*?

> XYZ Carpentry Services were *engaged* to made/manufacture/build/construct the chair.

Answer (score 0):

- **rendered**
- **executed** (*'design by me, implemented by craftsman'*)
- **implemented**